# Matrix of a Transformation of polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The Transformation of A is defined on the space $\mathcal{P}_2$ of polynomials $p$ such that $\deg(p)\leq2$ by $Ap(t) = p'(t)$.  Find the matrix of this transformation in the basis $\{1,t,t^2\}$.  What is $Ker(A)$?

I know that you find the $Ker(A)$ from $Ax=0$.  So is the $Ker(A) = 0$?

What is the approach for finding the matrix?

Comment: Isn't your basis outside of your vector space?

Comment: Fixed.  I am too used to working in $\mathbb{R}^3$ that I typed the wrong basis.

Comment: Are you sure $Ap=Ap'$ is the intended relationship?

Comment: No, you are right.  It is Ap = p'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright. Let $\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}=1$, $\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}=t$, and $\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}=t^2$. Let's look at what your basis looks like under the transformation.

- $A(1)=0=\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}$ (differentiating a constant polynomial)
- $A(t)=1=\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}$ (slope of line)
- $A(t^2)=2t=\begin{bmatrix}0\\2\\0\end{bmatrix}$ (power rule)

Thus, we get the matrix to be $$A=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 2 \\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}.$$

What's the kernel? Well, that's asking what polynomials have derivative 0. Can you think of any? (See bulletpoint #1)

Comment: Ah.  $Ker(A) = \mathbb{R}$

Comment: @Confused_Engineer -- Or, more precisely, "the kernel is the space of constant polynomials."